# Как изменить input с заданным value?

Tags: reactjs

Как мне изменять input с заранее заданным value? 
Делаю редактирование определенных элементов, данные в value получаю из БД, ну и, идея в том, чтобы когда юзер нажимает на "Редактировать", у него появлялось окно с инпутом для редактирования выбранного элемента, а в инпуте была старая инфа

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const arr = { company: [{ companyName: "Apple" }] };

  const blockCreate = () => {
    return arr.company.map(project => (
      <input type="text" value={project.companyName} />
    ));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{blockCreate()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Сейчас в input ничего нельзя вписать, но при этом он выводит, то, что нужно
Как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо добавить состояние в компонент, чтобы `input` изменял `value` в зависимости от введённых данных.

Набросал пример решения с использованием `useState` хука. https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-diffie-v6qq1

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [companyName, setCompanyName] = useState("Apple");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={companyName}
          onChange={e => setCompanyName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Рекомендую почитать подробнее в официальной рекомендации про работу с событиями. https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html